# escaping numbers in array index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I was not having any luck with searching so if this is a duplicate please let me know rather than downvoting.

I have a script for a game server that fills a database with the character data (name, level, userid and character type).

Rather than deleting the whole sql table each time and recreating it, I have it perform a check on the character data in the table and compare and only update whats different. it all works nicely.

However, A certain few character names are causing issues.

`[09-Sep-2017 02:16:34 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 1OO4 in C:\Scripts\charlist.php on line 56`
`[09-Sep-2017 02:16:34 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 1zxx in C:\Scripts\charlist.php on line 56`

That is this part of the script:

`if ($current[$charName] !== $level) {`

Where `$current` is an array of all the characters already in the database, I have it populate the array as Name => Level

The characters are in the database but they are not updating due to the error its throwing (as seen above) I tried wrapping $charName in "" but it did not work.

If anyone can provide advice it would be greatly appreciated.

entire script for reference, can see where i've fixed it in here.

```
<?php
$ClanServer = "";
$SodServer = '';
$UID = "";
$PWD = "";
$file = 'C:\account.txt';
$errlog = ini_get('php_errors');
$ConnInfo = array("UID"=>"$UID", "PWD"=>"$PWD", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$ClanConn = sqlsrv_connect($ClanServer, $ConnInfo);
$SodConn = sqlsrv_connect($SodServer, $ConnInfo);

if (!$SodConn) {
    die('Connection Failed!');
} else {
    echo "Connection Successful!<br />".PHP_EOL;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM soddb.dbo.levellist";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($SodConn, $query, array(), array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));
    $current = array();
    $files = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['CharName'];
        $current["'".$name."'"] = $row['CharLevel'];
    }
    $rootDir = realpath('C:/PT-Server/DataServer/userdata/');
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        if (substr($name, -4) == '.dat') {
            $fOpen = fopen($name, "r");
            $fRead = fread($fOpen,filesize($name));
        /*  details  */
            $charLevel = substr($fRead,0xc8,1);
            $charClass = substr($fRead,0xc4,1);
            $charName = trim(substr($fRead,0x10,16),"\x00");
            $charID = trim(substr($fRead,0x2d0,16),"\x00");
            $level = ord($charLevel);
            @fclose($fOpen);
            $files[] = $charName;
            if ($charName == "")
            {
                unlink($name); // Delete char file with no name...
            }

        switch (ord($charClass)){
            case 1: $class = 'Fighter'; break;
            case 2: $class = 'Mechanician'; break;
            case 3: $class = 'Archer'; break;
            case 4: $class = 'Pikeman'; break;
            case 5: $class = 'Atalanta'; break;
            case 6: $class = 'Knight'; break;
            case 7: $class = 'Magician'; break;
            case 8: $class = 'Priestess'; break;
            case 9: $class = 'Assassin'; break;
            case 10: $class = 'Shaman'; break;
            }
        if (in_array("'".$charName."'",array_keys($current))) {
            if ($current["'".$charName."'"] !== $level) {
                $dbentry = "UPDATE soddb.dbo.levellist SET CharLevel='$level',CharClass='$class' WHERE CharName='$charName'";
                $clanupdate = "UPDATE clandb.dbo.ul SET ChLv='$level' WHERE ChName='$charName'";
                $enter = sqlsrv_query($SodConn, $dbentry); 
                sqlsrv_query($ClanConn, $clanupdate);
                if ($enter) {
                    echo "Update $charName, $level successful!<br />".PHP_EOL;  
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dbentry = "INSERT INTO soddb.dbo.Levellist ([ID], [CharName], [CharClass], [CharLevel]) VALUES ('$charID', '$charName', '$class', '$level') ";
            $clanupdate = "UPDATE clandb.dbo.ul SET ChLv='$level' WHERE ChName='$charName'";
            $enter = sqlsrv_query($SodConn, $dbentry); 
            sqlsrv_query($ClanConn, $clanupdate);
            if ($enter) {
                echo "Insert $charName, $level successful!<br />".PHP_EOL;  
            }
        }

        }
    }
    /*  Remove deleted characters  */
    foreach ($current as $k => $v) {
        if (!in_array($k, $files)) {
            $query = "DELETE FROM soddb.dbo.levellist WHERE CharName='$k'";
            sqlsrv_query($SodConn, $query);
        }
    }
    sqlsrv_close($ClanConn);
    sqlsrv_close($SodConn);
}
?>
```

Comment: can you provide us some more code?

Comment: You don't need to escape anything in array indexes. The problem is that `$charName` is not one of the names in the array. You need to figure out why your script is trying to look up nonexistent names. Without seeing any of your code it's impossible to know what the problem could be.

Comment: I could imagine that this is a case where too much attempts to escape and quote things causes trouble. You should only use one single strategy to prevent broken sql statements based on client side input: the combination of "prepared statements" with "parameter binding". That is all you need and certainly the preferred strategy. Do not manually escape anything, do not manually place quotes around anything.

Comment: @barmar the name does exist in the array, it was needing to be encapsulated. i've nutted it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out, 
where I push the names to the array (`$current[$name] = $level;`)

I encapsulated that with '' which treats its as a string number a number (where the name was starting with a number)

so its now `$current["'".$name."'"] = $level;` and i did the same further down

```
if (in_array("'".$charName."'",array_keys($current))) {
      if ($current["'".$charName."'"] !== $level) {
           do stuff
      }
}
```

I've now run the script about 15 times to test and its not giving the issue at all.

Comment: This reads like a highly confused strategy in your setup, sorry.

Comment: i cut all the irrelevant crap out but basically first check is if its in the array, if its not then it will create a new entry for it (the character that is, in the case of new characters etc), if it is in the array, then the second IF block is see if the level has changed ($level is the characters level as its pulled from the character file) , if its different to current it will update, if its the same as current it doesnt touch it, no point updating something that hasnt changed.

Comment: Why would you do all that in php. Sounds as if this should be done inside the database...

Comment: because its reading the data from character '.dat' files, i'd have written it into a c++ or C# or python program if I could, but I know how to with php so I did it with php.  The database is purely to reference on the website so that the players can see rankings etc. the game does not use the database.

Comment: You store runtime data in a file? That should be extremely slow but even then I would suggest to use a file based database, especially for the update. So something like `sqlite`.

Comment: I didnt build the game, if I did it would all be direct to the database. its how the game was made. (written in like 1998 by a korean company) If I had the source code I would have changed it long ago